# Adding field to Profile when creating User

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a signup form that looks like this:

```
class SignUpForm(UserForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=32, min_length=1)
    initials = forms.CharField(max_length=3)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())'
    ...
```

I'm creating the user like this:

```
class SignUpView(FormView, LoginErrorView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    template_name = "website/sign_up.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                    email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                    password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
        ....
```

The Profile model looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    initials = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    ....
```

I'm creating the profile like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

What I would like to do is to save initials in post_save/create_user_profile (in the Profile-model) from the SignUpForm when I'm creating the Profile object, but I can't figure out any simple way of doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can save profile just after saving user. Try this:

```
class SignUpView(FormView, LoginErrorView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    template_name = "website/sign_up.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = User.objects.create(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                    email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                    password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, initials=form.cleaned_data['initials'])
```

Remove post_save. I hope this will work. If not, please comment.

Comment: This was the most obvious solution, but if it's possible I would like to get the initials into post_save. Any ideas on how to to that? I've updated the question with that information. I forgot to add that. :)